# How to return a vector of boxed traits using map (functional rather than imperative)

Tags: rust, traits

I'm new to Rust, and I'm only just beginning to grasp some core concepts.

In my case, I need to return a vector of boxed traits. I'd like to do it in functional programming style, but I can't get it to compile.

Can someone explain why the below code works when I use a `for` loop (imperative style), but doesn't work when using a functional programming style using an iterator (`filter_map` in this case)?

*Note:* this is a contrived example and has been reduced to the simplest form I could write in order to demonstrate my misunderstanding.

```
#![allow(unused_variables)]

struct Foo {}
struct Bar {}

trait Thing {}

impl Thing for Foo {}
impl Thing for Bar {}

fn main() {
    let things = get_things_using_for_loop(); // works!
    let things = get_things_using_iterator(); // doesn't work! :-(
}

fn get_things_using_for_loop() -> Vec<Box<Thing>> {
    let mut things: Vec<Box<Thing>> = vec![];
    for t in ["foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string()].iter() {
        if t == "foo" {
            things.push(Box::new(Foo {}))
        } else if t == "bar" {
            things.push(Box::new(Bar {}))
        }
    }
    things
}

fn get_things_using_iterator() -> Vec<Box<Thing>> {
    ["foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string()]
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|t| {
            if t == "foo" {
                Some(Box::new(Foo {}))
            } else if t == "bar" {
                Some(Box::new(Bar {}))
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
        .collect()
}
```

The function `get_things_using_for_loop()` compiles, while the function `get_things_using_iterator()` does not.

Here is the error:

```
error: mismatched types [--explain E0308]
  --> <anon>:23:31
   |>
23 |>                 Some(Box::new(Bar {}))
   |>                               ^^^^^^ expected struct `Foo`, found struct `Bar`
note: expected type `Foo`
note:    found type `Bar`
```

Comment: After typing this out, I'm thinking maybe the closure needs an explicit return type??

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you don't need to call `.to_string()` so much if you compare against `*t` instead of just `t`. The reason for the `*` is because an iterator over an array yields references to (not copies of) the array's elements. `.to_string()` makes it work, but is kind of convoluted by comparison.

Comment: Oh, thanks @trentcl!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with functional vs. imperative. Just pure types:

```
struct Foo {}
struct Bar {}

trait Thing {}

impl Thing for Foo {}
impl Thing for Bar {}

fn main() {
    let t = "quux";

    if t == "foo" {
        Some(Box::new(Foo {}))
    } else if t == "bar" {
        Some(Box::new(Bar {}))
    } else {
        None
    };
}
```

What type is returned from the `if`/`else`? The first branch says it's an `Option<Box<Foo>>`. The second says it's `Option<Box<Bar>>`. Those aren't the same type. If you coerce the types:

```
if t == "foo" {
    Some(Box::new(Foo {}) as Box<Thing>)
} else if t == "bar" {
    Some(Box::new(Bar {}) as Box<Thing>)
} else {
    None
};
```

It will all work.

You can also specify the type of the value:

```
let x: Option<Box<Thing>> = if t == "foo" {
    Some(Box::new(Foo {}))
} else if t == "bar" {
    Some(Box::new(Bar {}))
} else {
    None
};
```

Or, like you said, specify the type by annotating the closure:

```
.filter_map(|t| -> Option<Box<Thing>> {
```

Answer (score 5):

This has actually nothing to do with those two programming styles, but is a mere coincidence of your code. In your first function you explicitly state the type of the vector:

```
let mut things: Vec<Box<Thing>> = vec![];
```

In your second function you never mention that you want a vector full of `Box<Thing>`. You only have an `if-else` construct, whose cases return:

- `Some(Box::new(Foo {}))`
- `Some(Box::new(Bar {}))`
- `None`

The compiler sees the first case and assumes: "OK, the programmer wants to return `Option<Box<Foo>>`". But then in the next case you have an `Option<Box<Bar>>`. Now the compiler is confused. But it won't search the whole type space to find a trait that is implemented by both types (`Foo` and `Bar`). Also: there could be multiple traits which are all implemented by both, `Foo` and `Bar`. My point: you *have* to tell the compiler something about `Thing`!

To do so, you have multiple choices, for example:

```
if t == "foo" {
    Some(Box::new(Foo {}) as Box<Thing>)
} else { /* ... */ }
```

Just adding `as Box<Thing>` to the *first* case is already enough and the compiler is happy.